# Getting contacts when ids are known

Tags: android, contacts

I have a list of 'n' contact ids corresponding to which I need to obtain the contact details. One simple way to make n queries using the contact ids and retrieve those contacts. But this will be very time-consuming especially if n is large. I would like to know if there is any simpler way to obtain these results (like batch query etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
Cursor c = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection,
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " in ("+comma_delimited_ids+") , null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
```

then you can loop the cursor

```
if (c!=null) {
            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
                       // your code to get details from cursor
            }
            c.close();
        }
```